# Stripe.js - Stripe 3D Secure shows and disappears after few seconds

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I'm integrating Stripe into my project and all is working fine. Except for one weird error with the 3D-secure modal.

When I use the test card that requires 3DS, the modal pops up and works fine. But when I use the normal card 4242 4242 4242 4242
using if :amount_in_usd: > 100.00 Authentication rules
[Authentication rules Image][1]

The modal shows for a few seconds and then disappears then goes to the redirect_url without authenticating & do the payment with success.

My Payment Intent status is "requires_payment_method"

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots of code. Include the text of the code in a code block within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Stripe `4242` test card is not enrolled for 3DS. Therefore when calling `confirmPayment`, then authentication flow is skipped as the payment is exempt from SCA regulations.